# The output I'm trying to print doesn't print, trying to make a text based alarm clock with a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to compare the current time to the values in a HashMap to print a notification message (like an alarm). However, it doesn't print when the current time hits the time equal to a value within the HashMap. Is this because there isn't enough time for the containsValue method to iterate of the HashMap or another reason? Here is my relevant code:

```
private SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");

@Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            String currentTime = getCurrentTime();
                if (callLog.containsValue(currentTime)) {
                    System.out.println("it works!");
                }
    }

public String getCurrentTime() {
        Date time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        String currentTIme = timeFormat.format(time);
        return currentTIme;
    }
```

**Edit:** Okay, I've figured out my problem with a few tweaks. My if check works if I run the program at the exact moment I set the alarm for. If I wait for the alarm to go off (say 2 minutes after the program runs) the message doesn't get sent. Modified code below:

```
private HashMap<Integer, String> callLog;
        private SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");
        private String wakeUpMessage = "This is your automatic wake up call for room number: ";
        private String nextCall;
        private Thread thread;

        public HotelSystem() {
            callLog = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
            this.thread = new Thread(this);
            this.thread.start();
            setAlarmTime(4, "20:45:00");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (callLog.containsValue(getCurrentTime())) {
                    System.out.println(getCurrentTime());
                    sendAlarmCall(4);
                }
            }
        }

        // sends a generic alarm call message followed by the room number
        public void sendAlarmCall(int roomNumber) {
            System.out.println(wakeUpMessage + roomNumber);
        }

public String getCurrentTime() {
        Date time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        String currentTIme = timeFormat.format(time);
        return currentTIme;
    }

    public void setAlarmTime(int roomNumber, String time) {
        Date alarmDate;
        try {
            alarmDate = timeFormat.parse(time);
            String alarmTime = timeFormat.format(alarmDate);
            callLog.put(roomNumber, alarmTime);
            System.out.println("You entered room number: " + roomNumber + " and wake up time of: " + alarmTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Please ensure you seperate the time with colons eg 07:30:00.");
        }

    }
```

**Edit 2:** Okay, so now it's really weird. It works for everything I put in except if seconds are equal to 00. I have no idea why it's doing this.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't see enough useful information posted to be able to understand your problem and help fix it. Hopefully others will do better than me with this, but if you don't get decent answers soon, consider upgrading the information in your question.

Comment: Did you try this with integers for the time (eg. date.getTime()/1000 gives the seconds as number)? And replace Date time=new Date(). Are you really looping in an endless 100% CPU time loop over the hashmap?

Comment: What is `callLog`? Have you put `currentTime` in it?

Comment: callLog is a LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>. The string contains a value that the user wants an alarm to be sounded at i.e. 07:00:00. The comparison of currentTime is to check to see if the current time is in the hash map (i.e. an alarm should be sounded). The intention is not to endlessly loop, it's just like that for now. Once this is resolved, it will only perform the check once every 5 minutes.

Comment: Maybe you should redesign the concept: if this is called every 5 minutes how do you want to get the matching alarms? containsValue() can't help you there. And another question: how to you fill the hashmap?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the matching alarms"? If there is an alarm matching the current time, it should print out a generic alarm message e.g. ("alarm"). At the moment, I fill the hashmap manually using: callLog.put(4, "08:00:00) but eventually it'll take input from console.

Comment: If you check the hashmap every 5 minutes, eg. 8:00:00/8:05:00, how to you want to find times like 8:01:05, 8:04:00, etc?

Comment: Might be too heavy weight for your purposes, but you might want to look at Quartz (quartz-scheduler.org) [apache-2.0 licensed]. The other option is to use Java's Timer class and redesign your approach.

Comment: @brummfondel - Times in between is irrelevant, as the restriction on alarm times is rounded to the nearest 5 minutes.

Comment: Then you should use numbers but not strings, round those numbers already to your values (eg. milli seconds /(1000*60*5)) and use a HashSet<Integer>.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure it never "hits the time equal to a value within the HashMap" as you say. Provided your standard output is working (console for System.out to write to), your if condition is never evaluated as true.

Method containsValue definitely has enough time to be evaluated. Something like interrupting a method in the middle of it's evaluation is not possible (at least in your case), unless you interrupt the whole thread.

**Possible solutions to look for:**

**a)** In debug mode, check what kind of string values are in your hashmap and how your currentTime string looks like. There may be a formatting issue. From your code, there is no way to tell what values callLog contains.

**b)** Do not compare time as strings. I understand you need to achieve resolution in seconds (millis or nanos could cause problems with "hitting the equals time"), but doing so by converting Date into a string is resource-heavy and slow way of doing this. What you can actually do is to create your own class, e.g. ScheduleTime with few primitive attributes (hour, minute, second ) and override hashCode() and equals() methods. There are tons of tutorials on how to do this properly, it is very easy.

**c)** run() method is not called as often as it should be. If you want to have time resolution in seconds, make sure this method is fired every second.

*Also consider using Thread.sleep() instead of creating and destroying the thread over and over again. But this way, you have to reference your hashmap as an attribute of the thread object. But HashMap is not ThreadSafe, for thread safety there is ConcurrentHashMap. But this is just a reccomendation.*

Answer (score 1):

If your programm is running all the time, using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor or simply java.util.Timer can help you. They allow storing timers which are called without CPU loops.

If you want to make it yourself a TreeMap using the alarm times as integer keys maybe a good start.